# How to set default values in filter_select() in Crosstalk() in R - Plotly

Tags: r, crosstalk

I'm developing a rmarkdown HTML with plotly based interactive charts. While I could accomplish everything I want to have in the chart, the filter_select() from crosstalk() is not letting me to set default values in it. So my charts during initial loading looks clumpsy and bad.

[Selecting a default value in an R plotly plot using a selectize box via crosstalk in R, using static html not shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64234585/selecting-a-default-value-in-an-r-plotly-plot-using-a-selectize-box-via-crosstal/67057755#67057755)

The above discussion has some inputs but I don't know how to make those edits in the crosstalk() as I'm not familiar with HTML/JavaScript.

Answer (score 11):

Borrowing the example from the linked question, you've got the following for starters:

````
---
output:
  html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}


library(plotly)
# example data 
dat <- tibble::tribble(~filterBy, ~x, ~y,
                    "a", 1, 1,
                    "b", 2, 1,
                    "a", 1, 2,
                    "b", 2, 2,
                    "a", 1, 3,
                    "b", 2, 3,
                    "a", 1, 2,
                    "b", 2, 3,
                    "c", 3, 1,
                    "c", 3, 2,
                    "c", 3, 3
                    )  

# initializing a crosstalk shared data object  
plotdat <- highlight_key(dat)

# Filter dropdown
question_filter <- crosstalk::filter_select(
   "filter", "Select a group to examine",
   plotdat, ~filterBy, multiple = F
)

# Plotting:
plot <-  plot_ly( plotdat, 
    x = ~x, y = ~y, text = ~filterBy,  mode = "markers+text", 
    textposition = "top", hoverinfo = "x+y"
  )
```
````

You would paste the js from the accepted answer below the end of the r code, just as if you were making a new `{r}` block beneath the first one.

````
```{js}
function filter_default() {
    document.getElementById("filter").getElementsByClassName("selectized") 
[0].selectize.setValue("a", false);
 }
window.onload = filter_default;
```
````

To get this to work for *you*, there are a few arguments you'll likely need to change in the `{js}` block.

**1.** First, you'll want to look back at what you used as the tag for your `filter_select` element.  This is the first argument.  In the example above, `filter_select("filter",` means that you have used "filter" as your tag for the filter.

Say we had instead used "lantern" as our id for the crosstalk filter.  You would change `document.getElementById("filter")` to `document.getElementById("lantern")` in the `{js}`.

**2.** Next, you'll want to look at what value is the default selection.  In the example, the value is set to "a" with the `selectize.setValue("a"` bit in the `{js}` block.  You have the ability to choose whatever value that exists in your data as a default.  If, for example, you have source data:

```
other_dat<-data.frame(light=c("bulb","sun","biological"),amount=c(50,1000,3))
```

you could use (keeping in mind that we have chosen to tag our filter_select as "lantern"):

````
```{js}
function filter_default() {
    document.getElementById("lantern").getElementsByClassName("selectized") 
[0].selectize.setValue("bulb", false);
 }
window.onload = filter_default;
```
````

to set the default filter_select value to "bulb", or:

````
```{js}
function filter_default() {
    document.getElementById("lantern").getElementsByClassName("selectized") 
[0].selectize.setValue("sun", false);
 }
window.onload = filter_default;
```
````

to set the default value to "sun".

Comment: This is great! Any idea how to do it for checkboxes? I've tinkered with the Java code, to no avail!

Comment: How would one go about setting the default value to the first unique value? (in your example, you don't know if `light` will contain "bulb", "sun", "biological", or other values, but you can only plot a single set at one time.)

Answer (score 2):

In case there are multiple select inputs on one page. Also, `$(document).ready()` works better than `window.onload`.

```js
function filter_default(){
  document.getElementById("course_name").getElementsByClassName("selectized")[0].selectize.setValue("Course 1",false) 
  document.getElementById("Student_Group_Name").getElementsByClassName("selectized")[0].selectize.setValue("Group 1",false)
  document.getElementById("student_group_name_2").getElementsByClassName("selectized")[0].selectize.setValue("Group 1",false)
}
    
$(document).ready(filter_default);
```