# Default value in filter_select crosstalk doesn't work with JS

Tags: r, quarto, crosstalk

I would like to use `crosstalk` with a default value using the `filter_select` function. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67058016/how-to-set-default-values-in-filter-select-in-crosstalk-in-r-plotly/68024136#68024136) answer gives a JavaScript option but it doesn't seem to work. We have to use the id of the function and a default value. This is the code:

````
```{js}
function filter_default() {
    document.getElementById("std_specie").getElementsByClassName("selectized") 
[0].selectize.setValue("setosa", false);
 }
window.onload = filter_default;
```
````

But the filter doesn't show a default value in the dashboard. Here is some reproducible code:

````
---
title: "Example"
format: dashboard
---

```{r}
library(crosstalk)
```

```{r}
sd <- SharedData$new(iris)
filter_select("std_specie", "Choose your specie", sd, ~Species)
```

```{js}
function filter_default() {
    document.getElementById("std_specie").getElementsByClassName("selectized") 
[0].selectize.setValue("setosa", false);
 }
window.onload = filter_default;
```
````

Output:

[image]

As you can see there is no default value. It would have been great to have a default selection [option](https://github.com/rstudio/crosstalk/pull/70). So I was wondering why this code isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content in your `selectize` control is dynamically loaded by the JS in the document's `<head>`. `window.onload` is triggered after the page content is loaded, but before the script generating the filter drop down has finished executing. So this triggers an error. You have two options:

### Quick and dirty solution

Just make your function check if the element is loaded and if not then call itself again 20ms later:

````
```{js}
function filter_default() {
  let el = document
    .getElementById("std_specie")
    .getElementsByClassName("selectized")[0];
  el ? el.selectize.setValue("setosa", true) : setTimeout(filter_default, 20);
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", filter_default);
```
````

This will work but you may not want to do this if you're building a proper web app. If for some reason the content never loads then this will never finish executing and the page may become unresponsive.

### Proper solution

First, put this in your HTML:

```
<script>
function filter_default() {
  document
    .getElementById("std_specie")
    .getElementsByClassName("selectized")[0]
    .selectize.setValue("setosa", true);
}
filter_default();
</script>
```

Generate your Quarto html then use the Python script I wrote in [Load Quarto html map data from json for Leaflet map generated in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77448028/load-quarto-html-map-data-from-json-for-leaflet-map-generated-in-r).

The relevant part of this script for your problem is that it will:

1. Remove all the `<script src = "*.js">` tags from the `<head>` of the html, storing the URLs to be loaded later.
2. Find the JS in `<script>` tags hardcoded into the body of the html and move the code to separate *.js files.
3. Insert a JS script into the `<head>` which uses [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) with chained `.then()` statements to do the following (in this order):

   - Dynamically load the scripts that were in the `<head>`.
   - Dynamically load the scripts that were in the `<body>`.
   - Render all elements with [`HTMLWidgets.staticRender()`](https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/blob/943a819bf1a6cc705a6d0efe99fbf38f13e6bc50/inst/www/htmlwidgets.js#L570).

The JS in the body of the document generated will not run until the JS in the head has finished executing. This will only work on a web server, and not locally, because of [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). But if you're only running this locally then I'd do the quick-and-dirty option.